# Sci-fi movie about a alien object found by farmer

Tags: identify-this-movie, science-fiction

I'm trying to remember the name of a movie where a father misses the birthday of his daughter, at some point, the man finds a alien object which sustains life around it, the man started to build a nuclear proof shelter at the same time he started to be followed by some agents, government agents as far as I can remember.
Here's some extra details:

- The movie is 4-6 years old
- Its not an animation
- Filmed in the United States, the main location is a farm
- The main characters are a man and his daughter
- There's a lot of social tension during the movie shown on the news
- The man sees something fall from the sky, he found this object and is healed by the object

Looks like this object contains a kind of technology that regenerates all types of life form. At some point this object is placed on a farm box, flowers and plants started to grow around it

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think the movie name is [Terminus](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3399896/) 2015 Australian science fiction drama.